# How can I add effects like vignette of increased contrast to android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I'm working on a camera app in android and want to add some custom effects like a vignette or increased contrast.  I know it can be done, because there are some camera apps out there that do it.  Does anyone know how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html#EFFECT_VIGNETTE